# ValueError: Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path

Tags: python, path, object-detection

I want to create a simple object detection project. Instead of parsing one image to the `.detectObjectsFromImage()`, I want to parse a Numpy array containing several images. I created a for loop that loops inside the images array, I selected the input as `images[x]`. It seems like I get an error because of the `output_image_path`. How should the output path look if I want to output different images in different files in the same folder?

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import glob
import cv2

detector = ObjectDetection()

model_path = "/Users/dumitrescucristian/Desktop/Object_detection/models/yolo-tiny.h5"
output_path = "/Users/dumitrescucristian/Desktop/Object_detection/output"

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("/Users/dumitrescucristian/Desktop/Object_detection/input/*.jpg")]

detector.setModelTypeAsTinyYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(model_path)
detector.loadModel()

for x in range(len(images)):
    detection[x] = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=images[x], output_image_path=output_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by dowgrading to tensorflow 2.4.1, and to python < 3.9. It seems tensorflow 2.5-rc is the problem.